# How quasinormal modes of black holes related to black hole temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, perturbation-theory

I have heard that quasinormal modes of black holes are related to black hole temperature. QNMs describe how a black hole reacts to perturbation. Forex, when a black hole is perturbed, it will emit gravitational waves. If I am not wrong, Quasinormal mode frequencies are the frequencies of these
emitted gravitational waves, which decay exponentially. How can these be related to black hole temperature?  I am looking for some references for this. Could anyone suggest me any reference where I can learn why and how quasinormal modes are related to black hole temperature?

Comment: yes yes! and also- how are quasi-normal modes related to event horizon area?

Comment: Reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4014